# Docker error: The system cannot find the path specified

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

[The backend service could not up]

$ nx run core:docker-compose:up

> NX   Running global Nx CLI with PNPM may have issues.

Prefer to use "pnpm" (https://pnpm.io/cli/exec) to execute commands in this workspace.
TIP  create a shortcut such as: doskey pnx=pnpm nx -- $*

> nx run core:setup-env

> nx run core:setup

> nx run core:docker-create-volumes
> The system cannot find the path specified.
> Warning: run-commands command "/bin/bash ./scripts/docker-create-volumes.sh" exited with non-zero status code

> NX   Running target docker-create-volumes for project core failed
> Failed tasks:

- core:docker-create-volumes

Hint: run the command with --verbose for more details.
Warning: run-commands command "pnpm nx docker-create-volumes" exited with non-zero status code

——————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————

> NX   Ran target docker-compose:up for project core and 2 task(s) they depend on (3s)

```
×    1/2 failed
√    1/2 succeeded [0 read from cache]
```